# requestMatchers("/").permitAll() not working. It asks for authentication despite permitAll()

Tags: spring, spring-boot, web, spring-security, basic-authentication

By doing requestMatchers("/").permitAll() when I go to the url "localhost:8080/" or "localhost:8080" it still asks for authentication. But I did requestMatchers("/*").permitAll() then it worked(I know why) but I wanna why just "/" isn't working.

```js
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class ApplicationSecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
                .cors(cors -> cors.disable())
                .authorizeHttpRequests(
                        auth -> auth
                                .requestMatchers("/").permitAll()
                                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults());

        return http.build();
    }
}
```

I also mapped it to the controller, but nothing came out of it.

```js
@GetMapping("/hello")
    public String homePage() {
        return "U r Seeing the home page!!!! WOOOOWWWWWWW!!!!";
    }
```

I tried with other urls like "/hello" too but same result.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this your lambda DSL looks incorrect.

```
@Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity.csrf().disable().authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> {
            auth.requestMatchers("/", "/**").permitAll();
            auth.anyRequest().authenticated();
        });

return httpSecurity.build();
```

Comment: It will obviously work for every single url because u gave "/**" .

Answer (score 0):

I would say issue is using requestMatchers method, which gets object as input, not String...
.requestMatchers(request -> request.getRequestURI().contains("/actuator")).permitAll()

I usually use antMatchers instead
.antMatchers("/actuator").permitAll()

Also can be used regexMatchers, which also takes string as parameter - but antMatchers are more commonly used

Also the way how it is chained is a bit unusual

here is working example:

```
    http
            .anonymous().disable()
            .csrf().disable()
            .cors().disable()

            .anonymous()
            .and()

            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/actuator/health/liveness", "/actuator/health/readiness").permitAll()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/**").authenticated()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/**").authenticated()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.PUT, "/**").authenticated()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.DELETE, "/**").denyAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()

            .formLogin()
            .permitAll()
            .and()
```

...

Comment: I am using the  latest version of spring where most of the methods you are using here are deprecated.